# How can low rep users request account merges?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts, duplicate-accounts, merge

I've seen a number of requests to merge two accounts, posted here on meta and actioned by moderators. But what if a user has [less than 5 reputation](https://meta.askubuntu.com/faq#reputation), and thus cannot post a question on meta. What is the best way for such a user to get their two separate AskUbuntu accounts merged into one?

Comment: just an observation...a user with more than one account should certainly have more than 5 rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user noticing an account merged is required can flag any number of the posts to bring it to moderator attention.

Comment: Isn't there a rep requirement to raise a flag? I think it's 15 rep.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-ζ-- You can flag _your own_ posts no matter how low your rep is.